# How long can we live outside of Poland and not lose temporary resident permit rights?

Tags: resident-permit, eu, poland

I have a temporary resident permit for Poland until the end of 2023. I received permission to work remotely. So, I decided to leave and return to my country. For my thesis defense, I have been told that I should return. So, can I live outside of the EU for any time I want and return without a problem before the expiry date? Please note  that my residence permit issued by Poland and I exited from Germany.

Also, my wife is my dependent and in the same situation. Can she spend, say, 1 year outside of Poland with a temporary resident permit scheduled to expire at the end of 2023 and return to the EU for a conference in the Netherlands?

I guess that these work like D type schegen national visa normally issued for one year. someone can enter exit whenever he wants, right?

Comment: Believe that this question would be better suited for Expatriates SE.

Comment: I agree. Perhaps one of the mods will move it.

Comment: Usually (and I don't know any details for Poland), it's possible to leave and enter as long as the permit is valid BUT moving away or staying out of the country for too long may make the permit invalid (or prompt the authorities to move to invalidate it). There is no absolute guarantee the permit will remain valid until the date that's printed on it, there might be other rules in the law. In other words, the question is not really whether you can enter and exit as long the permit is valid but whether it will stay valid without residing in the country that issued it.

Comment: @ Relaxed I think unless the place you work or study allows you to work or study remotely there will be no problem. I dont know who to ask. And by the way I exit from Germany and I think the time I enter from other country than Poland then the risk is really low since the card will not be invalidated automatically and this is not written anywhere in law.. I am sure about it.

Comment: I agree the risk is probably low but let's try not to confuse the rule and its enforcement. If you are confident that you can retain your right to reside in Poland even after a year of absence or more then it doesn't matter at all that you exit through Germany. Conversely, if you rely on the fact you are leaving and entering through another country and the Polish authorities won't know about it, it means you are afraid your right of residence and your permit are not completely safe. It's important to clarify the question to get the right answer.

Comment: No man there is no fear! I am a phd researcher and my institute allows me to work from my country. Anyway they said that for defense of thesis you should he present here. Anyway I get paid and they will be helpful. The worst scrnario is defending online. However I asked embaddy amd waiting answet but I think temporary rp as far as you keep ypur position does not affect anything

Comment: @AhmadTurani That's another point I hesitated to raise earlier, the fact your institute allows you to work abroad is mostly irrelevant. If you are still considered a resident and have a valid permit then entering is not relevant. But why mention leaving through Germany or ask about losing the permit if you already know there is no risk?

Comment: Ohhh ok I see. Actually it is really important. If someone leaves or resigns from work the workplace should inform imimigration. The thing i mentioned is that I do not lose my status and as far as i know this is first thing for immigration. By the wsy this is temporary resident permit not long term.

Comment: The main purpose of a **residence permit** is permission to **reside** in a country. In Poland (just as in Germany) you must register your place of residence (in the country). If you give up your residence you must de-register. When you do so it will probably be reported to the immigration office and if no new address in Poland is found, they will assume you have permanently left and invalidate the residence permit.

Comment: What you (and your wife) need is a **multi-entry** visa for your occasional return visits. This is especialy true since after the introducton of the **Entry/Exit System (EES)** (expected in May 2023), the 2016-04-06 proposed amendment to the Schengen Borders Code (Article 8 (3)(a)(ii)) will include checks on the validity of residence permits upon entry to the Schengen Area.

Comment: The main purpose of rp card is to allow you whenever you wish to leave or turn back. In poland when you apply for card and visa finish hey stamp your passport means that you could stay inside poland until rp ready. It might take even 1 year!

Comment: National D type multi visa is same as rp. D type visa normslly one year. Enter today leave 363 days turn back last day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the answer given by immigration poland here to just show you I guessed correctly.if you doubt you can ask yourself. If someone keep his work study stable there is no problem. You can live outside for how many years you want and turn back one hour before expiry date. Of coursr if you enter from same country they will investigate and worst scenario ask from work place whether they have still contract or working. If you enter from another schengen absolutely nothing will be happened.

Dzień dobry,
nie ma ograniczeń odnośnie wyjazdów z kraju. Natomiast przy powrocie
należy wykazać możliwość legalnego pobytu na terenie Polski. Z tego co Pan
napisał, w tym przypadku będzie to zezwolenie na pobyt czasowy.